# Passing Property Classes to Plugin Infrastructure

Tags: c#, object, plugins, properties, reference

I have the following problem on which I need some advice.

I have a configuration that has a large number of plugin defined by a standard IPlugin interface struture.
Each of these interfaces needs access to a large number of external classes which define properties of many 
custom types.further these classes are inhereted from many base clases.

The issue here is one of design on how to present these property classes to each of the plugins in
order to fully access these structures.

To expand a little some classes have multiple lists, for sake of discussion up to 50 lists each having sub items
of 30 to 60 various propeties.

Now I can of course move all the property clases to the interface class as dependents, but as most of these clases
are inherted it becomes a horible solution. passing as ref object also does not appear to be a workable solution.

I have not included any speific code as I dont think it would help but here is a little psudo version of what I need to
achieve.

```
public interface IPlugin
{
ResultsList PluginProcess(Class1 L1, Class2 L2, ...);

}
```

class(n)  may be

```
public class Class1 : SomeOtherClass
{
public object1 obj1   {get; set; }
...
public object50 obj50 { get; set;}
}
```

and mainly consists of other derived objects.

Within the plugins I need to be able to use code such as

```
L1.classes.data[0].codec[2].enabled = true;
and 
L2 newclass2 = new L2();
newclass2.nnnn ...

ResultsList.classes.Add(newclass2);
```

Finaly I need to use a Plugin architecture in order for third partys to supply custom processing of the data.

Any constructive suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider an interface based around a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Into that `Dictionary` add all of your classes with useful identifiers.

```
dictionary["Class1"] = new Class1(...);
dictionary["Class2"] = new Class2(...);
```

Then pass the `Dictionary` into your interface.

```
ResultsList PluginProcess(Dictionary<string, object> context);
```

This will allow you provide arbitrary data to your consumers. You can use API documentation to describe which `Key` to use to get each class. This allows you flexibility to grow the interface input over time.

Its probably worth taking this a step further and having a special class for the plugin context.

```
class Context
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Values;

    ...
}
```

You can then pass the `Context` object into your interface.

```
ResultsList PluginProcess(Context context);
```

This gives you a lot of flexibility to grow the interface inputs over time. You can also provide additional functions and data on the `Context` to assist your consumers.

Comment: I did look at a dictionary interface but was put of by the bench marks on search times, as there would be many searches required to access the property names and values. Given your suggestion I will have another look.  If I pass by object and look at the locals with Visual Studio all property classes are there, I hoped for some easy and clever way to access that data.  Thanks